# Postgres equivalent for Oracle's DBA_FREE_SPACE and DBA_DATA_FILES

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

This is the sql query. I need to convert into postgres query

```
SELECT a.tablespace_name,
       a.maxbytes,
       a.mbytes,
       (a.maxbytes - a.mbytes),
       ROUND(((a.maxbytes - a.mbytes) / a.maxbytes)*100,2) AS fieldvalues
FROM (
  SELECT tablespace_name,
         SUM(maxbytes / 1024 / 1024) maxbytes,
         SUM(bytes / 1024 / 1024) mbytes
  FROM dba_data_files
  WHERE tablespace_name IN (SELECT tablespace_name
                            FROM dba_segments
                            WHERE OWNER = 'TEST')
  GROUP BY tablespace_name
) a,
  (SELECT tablespace_name,
         SUM(bytes / 1024 / 1024) mbytes
  FROM dba_free_space
  WHERE tablespace_name IN (SELECT tablespace_name
                            FROM dba_segments
                            WHERE OWNER = 'TEST')
  GROUP BY tablespace_name
) b
WHERE a.tablespace_name = b.tablespace_name
ORDER BY a.tablespace_name
```

Comment: I need to convert the above mentioned SQL query into Postgres Query

Comment: what's stopping you? We are not a free code conversion service (although I sometimes wonder...)

Comment: And what do you want us to do about that? SO is not a coding service. Do you have any problem?

Comment: I need dba_free_space,dba_data_files,dba_segments equivalent table name in postgres

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: there is no equivalent query in Postgres.

---

The tablespace concept in Postgres is **completely** different to Oracle's tablespace concept. Postgres doesn't have container files. [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html) each table is stored in one (or more files) specific to that table. A tablespace is nothing more then a directory on the harddisk.

Because of that, no such thing as `DBA_FREE_SPACE` exists (or is necessary) in Postgres.

To calculate the size of a single database, you can use e.g.

```
select pg_database_size('my_database_name');
```

To calculate the size of all tables in a schema, use

```
select table_schema,
       table_name,
       pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size (format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name)))
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
order by pg_total_relation_size(format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name)) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is said above, the concept of [postgres tablespace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) is similar to Oracle tablespace that

- it is a logical construct
- you can use each tablespace to store files on separate mount point and thus can have separate disks etc.

But the concept of PCT used and PCT used does not exist in Postgres - where PCT used is 100 and PCT free is zero. So if you start with a blank table, then rows are always added till the block is full.

Then, if you delete space, space is marked for deletion but deleted space is not recovered until a special process called [vacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/routine-vacuuming.html) runs. Furthermore if you update data new row is inserted and old one is marked as stale and later cleaned up as part of vacuum process.

To see how Postgres manages free space, read this [blog](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/postgres-physical-storage-tarun-annapareddy/)